# Symfony2 Model reverse DataTransformer on Collection using dynamic form generation and events

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a **Contract** entity that has a Collection of **TimekeepingEntries**.
Normally I would simply create a form mapped to a **Contract** and add a **collection** for the **TimekeepingEntries**.

Unfortunately the form has to be very custom - grouped by user and adapted to a weekday table created inside a loop using a dynamic vars named **days**.

This is the expected HTML result:
https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/42c3cdc6013fb09f1c58#file-batch-html

My form will have to create a collectionType **timekeepingEntry** for each day and for each user even if there is no data from the database.

This can be achieved by using the **PRE_SET_DATA** event and dynamically adding "sub-forms".
I havn't found a different way to dynamically add the collections that's why I had to use several *createNamed* methods:
https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/42c3cdc6013fb09f1c58#file-timekeepingentrybatchtype-php

So far the form works as it gets generated AND populated correctely.

But after submitting I get the following error:
**Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Plusquam\Bundle\ContractBundle\Entity\Contract::addTimekeepingEntry() must be an instance of Plusquam\Bundle\ContractBundle\Entity\TimekeepingEntry, array given**

Which is correct because I HAVE TO REVERSE TRANSFORM my custom array notation of the dynamic generated "sub-forms" back the collection entities **TimekeepingEntry**.

Unfortunately the *reverseTransform* method is not called:
https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/42c3cdc6013fb09f1c58#file-timekeepingtransformer-php

But this seems to be an expected behaviour as @webmozart aka @bernhard-schussek states:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7807

Is there a way to use the reverse Transformer? Is there a better way to create the dynamic collections - maybe using the *collection* field type?